# Is it possible to play Splitscreen Online?

Tags: ps4, star-wars-battlefront-2015

Is it possible to play splitscreen online in starwars battlefront on the ps4. I've tried to invite my friends to the party, and then play, but that doesn't work. Please respond to me if you know

Comment: Titles and tags aren't fillers, they are key parts of the question. Please be more careful when picking them.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. You have to be in the same party, and that is not possible from the same IP.

To make matters even worse, you cannot play together online even when you have 2 PS4's. PSN's servers detects the fact that this is being sent from the same IP and does not allow you to join eachothers party

Source: own experience and testing